# Duration of PostgreSQL ALTER COLUMN TYPE int to bigint

Tags: postgresql, type-conversion, time-complexity, postgresql-10

Let's say I have a table that has an `id` that is an `INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY`

I'm looking to document how to change the type, if in the future an `integer` is too small and I need to change the id type from `integer` to `bigint`. I'm mainly worried about the time complexity of the change, since it will likely occur when there number of rows in the table would be near the maximum number an integer type can store.

What would the time complexity for the following command be?

```
ALTER TABLE project ALTER COLUMN id TYPE BIGINT;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This command will have to rewrite the whole table, because `bigint` takes 8 bytes of storage rather than the 4 of an `integer`. The table will be locked from concurrent access while this is taking place, so with a big table you should be prepared for a longer downtime.

If you expect that this could be necessary, perform the change as soon as possible, while the table is still small.

Comment: Is this still the case in Postgres 12? The [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-altertable.html) state:

_Adding a column with a volatile DEFAULT or changing the type of an existing column will require the entire table and its indexes to be rewritten. As an exception, when changing the type of an existing column, if the USING clause does not change the column contents and the old type is either binary coercible to the new type or an unconstrained domain over the new type, a table rewrite is not needed; but any indexes on the affected columns must still be rebuilt._

Comment: @MatthiasLohscheidt A data type of size 4 is never binary coercible to a data type of length 8. Binary coercible means that the storage format is identical. There are more complicated ways to achieve the goal that require no down time, but not a simple `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Laurenz Albe! I wasn't sure what "unconstrained domain" meant, but now I guess it refers to [domain types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/domains.html) (which are still binary coercible in the end).